# Is there a way to programatically position status bar item in the status bar (OSX)?

Tags: macos, swift

Is there any way to choose where about in the status bar my item goes. For example, out of all status bar items (apart from default Apple items like date and time) can I choose to put it to the far left, or far right etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Objective-C Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975536/is-it-possible-to-add-a-nsstatusitem-to-a-specific-position-in-nsstatusbar), I don't think Apple has an official way or API to allow that. I also could not find any help in their documentation.

You should be able to use private APIs, though.